# What happened to the other Atlas Cruisers?

Tags: rwby

In the *RWBY* episode "Battle of Beacon," a major turning point is the moment when

> Roman Torchwick captures one Atlas cruiser and shoots down two more, 
>  effectively leaving Vale defenseless and the Atlesian Knights under 
>  Torchwick's control.

This image from the previous episode "PvP", however, clearly shows that there are at least seven such cruisers present in Vale at the time of this occurrence. 
[image: Seven Atlas Cruisers]

Has it ever been explained what happened to the other four cruisers, and why they were unable to do anything about the events that followed?

> Particularly the destruction of Beacon Tower, and the deaths and injuries
>  caused by the Grimm/White Fang attack.

Answer (score 2):

We don't see them again, but we can look at how things went and take a guess. Mine would be that **at least part of them were dedicated to the evacuation effort**.

In chapter 10 "Battle of Beacon", when the Nevermore and Griffons first break inside the Colosseum, things are bad, granted, but people are being evacuated with the "bus" ships that took them there in the first place:

[image: Bus ships]

It's apparently only the Colosseum. Havok is coming to Beacon, but they don't know that yet. Atlasian Army can afford to leave its Crusaders in the air.

---

Later, in chapter 11, "Heroes and Monsters", the situation has changed big time. Atlasian Army is down three ships out of seven, and the machines are out of their control. On top of that, there's a huge Grimm dragon dropping new Grimm everywhere. It's not a fighting time anymore, it's retreat time. [Ironwood orders](https://youtu.be/pT1XiUbJu_Y?t=10m39s):

> Glynda, form up with the local Huntsmen and establish a safe zone here in Vale. We need to evacuate Beacon. Qrow, I'm leaving that to you and my men.

They went from evacuating the Colosseum, to evacuating the whole school of Beacon. Also, Ironwood and Qrow not teasing each other will tell you how dire the situation is.

Here's an insight of what the inside of the "bus" ships look like:

[image: Inside bus ships]

For comparison, look at the inside of Atlas Cruisers:

[image: Atlas crusader interior]

It's not as comfy, but you can fit people in there. *Especially* when you have to evacuate people in times of war, you don't get too picky.

---

Then, chapter 12, "End of the Beginning", opens with Yang, Ren, Nora and Blake about to get evacuated. Note [these lines](https://youtu.be/hq1lk-QWxNg?t=2m5s):

> Port: That's it, everybody on board. This is a mandatory evacuation.
>
> Oobleck: A safe zone has been established in Vale. Please remain calm and **listen to Atlas personnel**.
>
> [...]
>
> Sun: She's gonna be okay. **The soldiers have a ship ready to take you guys to Vale**.

The "Atlas personnel" and the "soldiers" are likely the same people. Hence, **I think it's safe to say some ships were being used as "regular" transport vehicles**, with presumably the added advantage of maniability and weaponry/defense, which is a nice bonus to protect people.